# How to call a callback function in a thread from Microsoft RPC Server

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, rpc

My server is trying to call an RPC Callback function from within a thread. Following the example [How To Use RPC Callback Functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/96781/how-to-use-rpc-callback-functions)
 , and expanding slightly this is what I am attempting to do

```
   [ SAMPLE.IDL ]
   [
      uuid(9FEE4F51-0396-101A-AE4F-08002B2D0065),
      version(1.0),
      pointer_default( unique )
   ]

   {
       void RPCProc( [in, string] unsigned char *pszStr );
       [callback] void CallbackProc([in,string] unsigned char *pszStr);
   }


   [ SAMPLEC.C (Client)]
     void CallbackProc( unsigned char *pszString )
     {
       printf("Call from server, printed on client: %s", pszStr );
     }


   [ SAMPLES.C (Server)]
     DWORD WINAPI thread(LPVOID lp)
     {
       CallbackProc(lp);
       return 0;
     }

     void RPCProc( unsigned char *pszStr )
     {
       // WORKS
       CallbackProc(pszStr);

       // WORKS
       thread(pszStr);

       // Exception: 0x000006A6  binding handle invalid
       HANDLE h = CreateThread(NULL, 0, thread, pszStr, 0, NULL);
       WaitForSingleObject(h, INFINITE);
     }
```

When CallbackProc is called from within a thread is when the exception is thrown.

Comment: Why create a thread when all you do in the creating thread is wait for the new thread to terminate?  Why not just call the exception-handler function directly?

Comment: This is the simplistic view. My code does more. If you ran this sample it would throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late, but I think the problem is that the information to call the callback is per thread. Every time you call a server, the server create a thread and it links the binding handle to that thread. If you add the fact you can call callback only during a client request, it is reasonable you can't call a callback in a thread different of that that wait on client request.